# Trim dynamicBuffer to maintain size

Tags: java, jboss, buffer, netty, fragmentation

I'm using ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer() to manage fragmentation of unknown size messages over a network using Netty. My question is, when I readBytes(...) from the buffer, do the bytes that got read automatically get "trimmed" from the buffer so it doesn't grow to a ridiculous size over time? If not, how would I go about doing this myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not trim it self. It even not allow to trim later. The only way you can do this is to create a new one.

Comment: In Netty 4, all buffers are dynamic and you can shrink the capacity by calling `ByteBuf.capacity(int)` with the smaller capacity.